# C - recursively copying files

Tags: c, recursion, stat

I dont know why but I am not finding where the problem is. I run a test to see if it is a directory or a file and even the files get considered as folders.

The problem is that while running the loop even for the files it goes into the directory process and postrs  " file1   for directories"

Here is the code:

```
void copie_dossier(char *doss1, char *doss2) {
    struct dirent *dptr;
    DIR *dp;
    struct stat stbuf;

    char newDest[strlen(doss2) + 1];
    char tempSrc[strlen(doss1) + 1];
    strcat(doss2, "/");
    strcat(doss1, "/");
    strcpy(newDest, doss2);
    strcpy(tempSrc, doss1);

    stat(doss1, &stbuf);

    dp = opendir(doss1);

    /*
    if (!dp) {
       perror("open_dir");
       exit(1);
    }
    */

    if (!(dp))
        return;
    if (!(dptr = readdir(dp)))
        return;

    int mk = mkdir(doss2, 0777);
    if (mk == -1) {
        perror("create_dir");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((dptr = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        struct stat stbuf2;
        //stat(dptr->d_name, &stbuf2);
        char *new = dptr->d_name;

        if (!strcmp(dptr->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dptr->d_name, "..")) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!stat(tempSrc, &stbuf2)) {
            if (S_ISREG(stbuf.st_mode)) {
                printf("%s for files\n", dptr->d_name);
                strcat(newDest, dptr->d_name);
                strcat(tempSrc, dptr->d_name);
                copy_files(tempSrc, newDest);
                strcpy(newDest, doss2);
                strcpy(tempSrc, doss1);
            }

            if (S_ISDIR(stbuf.st_mode)) {
                printf("%s for directory \n", dptr->d_name);
                strcat(newDest, dptr->d_name);
                strcat(tempSrc, dptr->d_name);
                copie_dossier(tempSrc, newDest);
                strcpy(newDest, doss2);
                strcpy(tempSrc, doss1);
            } 
        }
    }
    closedir(dp);
}
```

Comment: What are your error messages?

Comment: Please search a little. There are *thousands* of examples on how to recursively enter directories on this site alone, not to mention the whole of the Internet where there are probably millions of examples.

Comment: Basically the code runs fine...but the test considers the files to be folders so it does nothing with them

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes I know there are many exemples...Its hsould be working fine but it does not..That is my problem .

Comment: All the other thousands of 'my file/folder macro doesn't work' turn out to have bad paths.

Comment: Post the rest of the function.  How is `stbuf` filled? is it a static structure?

Comment: @chqrlie I posted the rest of it

Comment: @K.Xhel: you must learn to indent your code more consistently.  As posted it was unreadable.  Use spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: @K.Xhel: There are many problems in your code, I posted a corrected version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the allocation of the local buffers:

```
char newDest[strlen(doss2) + 1];
char tempSrc[strlen(doss1) + 1];
strcat(doss2, "/");
strcat(doss1, "/");
strcpy(newDest, doss2);
strcpy(tempSrc, doss1);
```

Even the very first use of `newDest` and `tempSrc` invoke undefined behavior as you copy strings that do not fit in the destination.  `newDest` and `tempSrc` are allocated for exactly the number of characters in `doss1` and `doss2` respectively (ad the final `'\0'`), but you append an extra `/` before copying.

Later in the code, you concatenate directory entry names, causing further undefined behavior.

You must change the logic for pathname composition.  You can use memory allocation or a global buffer in which you concatenate the entries while remembering where the pathname used to end to strip it back to the previous state.

There is another big issue in your test for directory / filename: You do not `stat()` the proper pathname and you use a separate `stbuf2` instead of the `stbuf`.  You should first create the pathname to the current entry, pass it to `stat()` and check for directory and filename on the resulting `stbuf`.

Here is an improved version:

```
char *make_path(const char *path, const char *name) {
    size_t len = strlen(path);
    char *p = malloc(len + 1 + strlen(name) + 1);
    if (p) {
        strcpy(p, path);
        p[len] = '/';
        strcpy(p + len + 1, name);
    }
    return p;
}

void copie_dossier(const char *doss1, const char *doss2) {
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dptr;

    dp = opendir(doss1);
    if (dp == NULL)
        return;

    int mk = mkdir(doss2, 0777);
    if (mk == -1) {
        perror("create_dir");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((dptr = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        struct stat stbuf;
        char *source, *dest;

        if (!strcmp(dptr->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dptr->d_name, "..")) {
            continue;
        }

        source = makepath(doss1, dptr->d_name);
        dest = makepath(doss2, dptr->d_name);
        if (!source || !dest) {
            perror("makepath");
            exit(1);
        }                
        if (!stat(source, &stbuf)) {
            if (S_ISREG(stbuf.st_mode)) {
                printf("%s for files\n", dptr->d_name);
                copy_files(source, dest);
            } else
            if (S_ISDIR(stbuf.st_mode)) {
                printf("%s for directory \n", dptr->d_name);
                copie_dossier(source, dest);
            } 
        } else {
            // should issue a diagnostic message
        }
        free(source);
        free(dest);
    }
    closedir(dp);
}
```

You did not post the code for function `copy_files`.  I assume it copies one file, despite the name.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot..the code I was using was mainly used only for directories apperently thats why it failed to recognize the file as I always added the '/' at the end . Thanks for the help and I will be more careful with the code format too.

Comment: @K.Xhel: Read and study my answer, the code was broken in several different ways.